# Is there an installation file for Node.js and MongoDB for Windows?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I'm thinking about learning Node.js and MongoDB after becoming enamored by Backbone.js after doing a short tutorial. Is there an stack like Wamp available that helps setting up Node.js and MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB can be downloaded [here](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) and is incredibly easy to install & run... just unzip to anywhere and run the mongod.exe or you can install & run as a Windows service if you prefer. More installation info [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Comment: Node is a single installer, very easy as well.